# background image rendering issue

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I'm having some issues with the background on certain mobile phones.

the styling for that div is:

```
#navPanel {
    background: url('images/bg04.jpg');
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.25), inset -2px 0px 25px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

it is rendering fine on a friends iPhone 6 which looks like this:

[image]

and when it renders on my iPhone 5s the background image is distorted: 
[image]

Any ideas why the background image would render this way? Does it have to do with the device's pixel density?

Sorry for the large images.

[ufc-info.com](http://ufc-info.com)

I made a quick fiddle and it is rendering as desired.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z4p0yb31/)

Comment: ir probably has to do with the damn retina display

Comment: I had a bad path on the mobile portion of my css. Sorry guys, I fixed the path and now the images are appearing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why it looks different, as I believe both devices have retina display. Anyway, you can use media query to target retina screens and supply a hi-res background image.

You current image bg04.jpg is 150x150, you need to find/create a hi-res version of it.

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    #navPanel {
        background-image: url('images/bg04@2x.jpg'); /* this image should be 300x300 */
        background-size: 150px 150px;
    }
}
```

Or quick try it like this, but the pattern will look slightly different.

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) {
    #navPanel {
        background-image: url('images/bg04.jpg'); /* current one 150x150 */
        background-size: 75px 75px; /* half */
    }
}
```